# Updating an "Inserted" column inside my "Insert" Trigger - a little different

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2014

I have researched quite a bit but couldn't find what I wanted-
(I have shallow knowledge on TRIGGERS in SQL- pardon me!)

Qn: I have all the THREE Triggers on my table (Insert, Update & Delete)
In my AFTER INSERT Trigger: I need to "update" the "inserted" column 
and I was using :

```
UPDATE Table_name
SET Column_name = @Input
(currently)
```

But I was requested to use something like:

```
 UPDATE "Inserted.column_name"
 SET Column_name = @Input
```

But this generally cannot happen as it throws me an error:

> The logical tables INSERTED and DELETED cannot be updated

Can someone help me out please?

I have seen posts on using `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` but that doesn't serve my purpose.. Thanks in advance! Appreciate your help!

Comment: You need to update *your underlying table* - not the `Inserted` pseudo table. Join your own table with the `Inserted` pseudo table on the primary key, and then update the **actual table** that's affected by this trigger operatoin

Comment: I already wrote the join on my psuedo table.. but can you further show an example please? I have written the join like this UPDATE table_name
   
   SET
    [Col_name] = @Input
   FROM Table t
   JOIN INSERTED ON t.Primary_key = INSERTED.Id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the **actual, underlying table** - not the `Inserted` pseudo table....

You need to join the tables on the primary key, and then update your actual data table - something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Insert_Sample
ON dbo.YourTableName
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE dbo.YourTableName
    SET SomeColumn = i.SomeValue
    FROM Inserted i 
    WHERE dbo.YourTableName.PrimaryKey = i.PrimaryKey
```

or something along those lines....

You **also** need to be aware that the trigger is called *once per statement* - not once per row - so if your `INSERT` statements inserts 10 rows at once (from e.g. a `SELECT`), your trigger is called **once**, and `Inserted` will contain **10 rows** - so you need to make sure your trigger code is capable of handling this situation and is written in a proper, set-based manner (no `SELECT @Value = SomeColumn FROM Inserted` - that won't work!)